# Why does calling next on an Iterator trait object give me an "out of memory" at runtime?

Tags: iterator, out-of-memory, rust

I implemented a `BoxedIterator` in Rust that just boxes another `Iterator` as a trait object. The full implementation is on [Github](https://github.com/Apanatshka/cargo-benchcmp/blob/add287a33321940e9410dac0e481f3b0e7b9faab/src/iterator.rs). Why does Rust compile this code without complaint but fail with an "out of memory" message (OOM) when it first tries to call `next` on the `Iterator` trait object in the `Box`?

As far as I can tell it doesn't allocate much memory before failing, so I'm inclined to think the OOM message is not correct.

```
//! BoxedIterator just wraps around a box of an iterator, it is an owned trait object.
//! This allows it to be used inside other data-structures, such as a `Result`.
//! That means that you can `.collect()` on an `I where I: Iterator<Result<V, E>>` and get out a
//! `Result<BoxedIterator<V>, E>`. And then you can `try!` it. At least, that was my use-case.

use std::iter::FromIterator;
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

pub struct BoxedIterator<T> {
    iter: Box<Iterator<Item = T>>,
}

impl<T> Iterator for BoxedIterator<T> {
    type Item = T;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.iter.next() // The OOM comes from this call of `next`
    }
}

impl<T> FromIterator<T> for BoxedIterator<T> {
    fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> Self
        where I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
              I::IntoIter: 'static
    {
        BoxedIterator { iter: Box::new(iter.into_iter()) }
    }
}

use std::fs::File;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let iter: Result<BoxedIterator<File>, io::Error> =
        vec!["/usr/bin/vi"].iter().cloned().map(File::open).collect();
    let mut iter = iter.unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
}
```

I don't think I'm going to use this code, as I've figured that my use case will need to traverse the `Iterator` of `Result`s completely to extract any errors so I might as well gather them in a `Vec` at that point. But I'm still curious about this OOM.

While creating a minimal example, I found that without doing the File IO, I get a segfault:

```
use iterator::BoxedIterator;

fn main() {
    let iter: Result<BoxedIterator<&str>, ()> = 
        vec![Ok("test1"), Ok("test2")].iter().cloned().collect();
    let mut iter = iter.unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
}
```

If I don't use any `Result`, just create a `BoxedIterator` with `collect`, the code works as expected:

```
use iterator::BoxedIterator;

fn main() {
    let mut iter: BoxedIterator<&str> = vec!["test1", "test2"].iter().cloned().collect();

    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
    // prints: Some("test1")
}
```

Comment: The OOM only happens in debug mode. In release mode the program runs fine https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5ada00482267db3ae94468b47ec0a014&version=stable&backtrace=0 . I think you should report this as a bug.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of reporting a bug for you (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34714).

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the text that indicates that this is an out-of-memory error? When I run it, I "just" get a segfault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation of `FromIterator` isn't correct; specifically, you aren't allowed to put an `I::IntoIter: 'static` bound in that position.  The bounds on your implementation have to match the bounds on the trait itself.  The compiler should diagnose this, [but currently doesn't](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18937).

At a higher level, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Where do you expect the `File` handles to be stored?  You would normally write something like this:

```
let files: Result<Vec<File>, io::Error> =
    ["/bin/bash"].iter().cloned().map(File::open).collect();
```

Comment: For the higher level question: see the note below the first piece of code (originally prefixed by N.B.) which is basically commenting on the uselessness of the code ^^ I indeed switched to collecting the `File` handles into a `Vec`.