# custom global allocator in rust allocate some big size layout at the begining

Tags: rust

I use some custom allocator in an custom arm cortex. I have heap overflow problem. When I logged allocator fundtion I found some big size allocation request. Any idea how to debug this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug a memory issue in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254937/how-do-i-debug-a-memory-issue-in-rust)

Comment: No , I don't think so. I have problem in allocation level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `backtrace` crate to figure out what is calling your allocator:

https://crates.io/crates/backtrace